# How to efficiently solve linear system with Laplacian + diagonal matrix?

Tags: matlab, system, sparse-matrix, factorization

In my implementation of an image processing algorithm, I have to solve a large linear system of the form `A*x=b`, where:

- Matrix `A=L+D` is the sum of a Laplacian matrix L and a diagonal matrix D
- Laplacian matrix L is sparse, with about 25 non-zeros per row
- The system is large, with as many unknowns as there are pixels in the input image (typically > 1 million).

The Laplacian matrix L does not change between successive runs of the algorithm; I can construct this matrix in preprocessing, and possibly compute its factorization. The diagonal matrix D and right-side vector b change at each run of the algorithm.

I am trying to find out what would be the fastest method to solve the system at runtime; I do not mind spending time on preprocessing (for computing a factorization of L, for example).

My initial idea was to pre-compute a Cholesky factorization of L, then update the factorization at runtime with values from D (rank-1 update with cholupdate), and solve quickly the problem with back-substitution. Unfortunately, the Cholesky factorization is not as sparse as the original L matrix, and just loading it from disk already takes 5.48s; as a comparison, it takes 8.30s to directly solve the system with backslash.

Given the shape of my matrices, is there any other method that you would recommend to speedup the solving at runtime, no matter how long it takes at preprocessing time?

Comment: Try SVD, I don't know how fast it is for that large amount of data though...

Comment: I fail to see why applying SVD here would be a good idea, given the form of my matrices.

Comment: yep, probably you are right, Im not an expert. Just in case you didnt take into account that :)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working on a grid (since you mention images - although this is not guaranteed), that you are more interested in speed than precision (since 5s seems already too slow for 1 million unknowns), I see several options.

First, forget about exact methods such as Cholesky (+reordering). Even if they allow to store the factorization and reuse it for multiple rhs, you'll likely need to store gigantic matrices that appear to be intractable in your case (I hope you're re-ordering rows/columns with reverse Cuthill McKee or anything else though - that sparsifies the factorization a lot).

Depending on your boundary conditions, I would first try a Matlab `poisolv` that solves a Poisson problem using an FFT, and possible reprojections if you want Dirichlet boundary conditions instead of periodic ones. It's very fast, but might not be appropriate for your problem (you mention having 25 nnz for a Laplacian matrix+identity : why ? is-it a high order Laplace matrix, in which case you may be more interested in precision than what I assume ? or is-it in fact a different problem than the one you describe ?).

Then, you can try multigrid solvers that are very fast for images and smooth problems. You can use a simple relaxation method for each iteration and each level of the multigrid, or use fancier methods (for instance, a preconditioned conjugate gradient par level). 
Alternatively, you can do a simpler preconditioned conjugate gradient (or even SSOR) without multigrid, and if you're only interested in an approximate solution, you can stop the iterations before full convergence.

My arguments for iterative solvers are:

- you can stop before convergence if you want an approximate problem
- you can still re-use other results to initialize your solution (for instance, if your different runs correspond to different frames of a video, then using the solution of the previous frame as an initialization of the next would make some sense).

Of course, a direct solver for which you can precompute, store and keep the factorization also makes sense (although I don't understand your argument for a rank-1 update if your matrix is constant) since only the backsubstitution remains to be done at runtime. But given this ignores the structure of the problem (a regular grid, a possible interest in limited precision results etc.), I'd opt for methods which have been designed for these cases such as Fourier-like methods or multigrids. Both methods can be implemented on the GPU for faster results (recall that GPUs are rather tailored for dealing with images/textures!).

Finally, you can get interesting answers from [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) which is more targeted to numerical analysis.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the reordering! I would just add incomplete Cholesky factorizations to your list, perfect otherwise!

Comment: thanks :) I was under the impression that incomplete Cholesky factorizations for preconditionning were much slower than a simple Jacobi preconditionner for only minor improvement in the speed of convergence ; isn't it?